# How to force select2 to open when click on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I use select2 in my website. I test it in the mobile device and found that **select2 opened when keydown event happen**. When the user tries to scroll the page and touch select2 element it opened while user wants to scroll page not use select2. This is not user-friendly. Now I like force select2 to opened when click on it.

Is this possible?

```
 $("#element").select2();
```

Comment: AFAIK, select2 doesn't open itself unless clicked on it. This is the default behaviour.

Comment: Click event while happen that left button of mouse pressed and then Mouse button released !!!!!!!  but select2 opened when left button of mouse pressed

Comment: This behaviour is also there with native `select` boxes.